# How to show 11 instead of 11.9655 in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I have a formula(**=O6/J6**) which resulting 11.9655.
But after reducing decimal it's showing 12. I want to display only 11 and it should be without decimal.

It should be look like this:-

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |Box qnty     |    Stock|  Stock as Box | Stock(as pcs) not full box one|
 |-------------+---------|------------------------------------------------
 |     200     |     2570|           12  |              170              |
 |    1200     |     3700|           3   |              100              |
 |    1300     |     4800|           3   |              900              |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you label the columns in the example, which is O, which is J,etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `TRUNC` function

```
=TRUNC(B1)
```

Assuming the 1st 2 columns in your example are provided data, and the next 2 are calculated and that the 1st cell of data resides as A1, for stock as box, you can use

`=TRUNC(B1/A1)`

and for

> Stock(as pcs) not full box one

you can use `=B1-A1*C1`

Comment: But i have another cell with below formula which now showing 0

**=MOD(P6,1)*J6** @Akash

Comment: @RonoCharlson In the example, which is the calculated field and which is already provided?

Comment: @RonoCharlson You can use =INT(stock/box_qty) as well. Also =MOD(x,1) returns the remainder after divided by 1. Since everything divisible by 1 the remainder is always 0. What are you trying to achieve? Please provide more excel sheet with more details.

Comment: Akash already solved my problem and i am happy with his answer. Thanks to you also for trying to solve my question. @Darius